# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, slf4j

There are a lot of solutions for this on the web and in StackOverflow.
I have implemented them (at least I tried): Without success.
The idea I understood I just have to have the right classes from sfl4j.
As the instruction at https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder tells,

> "Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem"

Some other instructions call for making the "api" class available.
I tried different combinations, but something I got wrong - the problem is not solved yet.
I dealt with:
slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar
slf4j-simple-2.0.9.jar
slf4j-reload4j-2.0.9.jar
slf4j-log4j12.jar
slf4j-jdk14-2.0.9.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.20.0.jar
As I m using simples eclipse without add-ons, I just added the jar files to classpath (Project Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries).
Here is the resulting classpath currently in use:

````
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/jchart2d/jchart2d-3.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Documents/Java WS/jssc/jssc-2.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Documents/Java WS/Lkmt/slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Documents/Java WS/Lkmt/slf4j-simple-2.0.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>```   

It could be it's more of an eclipse build issue, less than a slf4j issue.   
BTW, the logger is not needed by my design, but by the external lib jssc-2.9.5.jar.

Any ideas?
Thanks - Tarik
````

Comment: Try to add those dependency in your pom:
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j-slf4j-impl.version}</version>
          </dependency>